# Resize text when it is cut off

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I have a webpage with 2 divs that contain text side by side. I want the text size to remain the same for each, until the screen width cuts the text off, which at that point I would like the "width" of the div containing the 2 texts to be 100% of the screen size. This is so that my site looks the same on the desktop, but when viewed on mobile if the screen width is small enough to where the text cuts off, the text is then scaled to take up the screen width.

Here is my current html for this part:

```
<div id="fullname">
            <div class="firstname">First</div><div class="lastname">Second</div>
</div>
```

Along with the current css:

```
.firstname
{
    display: inline;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    width: .5em;
}

.lastname
{
    display: inline;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}

#fullname
{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use media query? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I autoscale the font size to fit the contents of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100766/how-can-i-autoscale-the-font-size-to-fit-the-contents-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries is your CSS to do it. Don't have the code with me, give me a minute...

EDIT: Put this in your CSS file instead:

```
.firstname
{
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: 900;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -3px;
width: .5em;
}

.lastname
{
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -3px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {

.firstname
{
display: inline;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: 900;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -3px;
width: .5em;
}

.lastname
{
display: inline;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -3px;
}

}

#fullname
{
max-width: 100%;
margin: 50px 10px 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```